# Symfony lock component doesn't lock in production

Tags: php, symfony, locking, symfony-3.4, symfony-lock

I upgraded to Symfony 3.4.* to take advantage of the new lock component. However it seems to work in dev however in production lock is always acquired. Here is my code:

BaseCommandWrapper:

```
<?php
namespace CoreBundle\Command;

ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); 

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Factory;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\SemaphoreStore;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;

class BaseCommandWrapper extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    use LockableTrait;

    function start($commandName) {

        $this->commandName = $commandName;

        $store = new SemaphoreStore();
        $factory = new Factory($store);

        $this->lock = $factory->createLock($this->commandName);

        if (!$this->lock->acquire()) {
            echo 'This command is already running in another process.' . PHP_EOL;
            return false;
        }

        echo "Lock aquired" . PHP_EOL;

        return $this->lock;
    }

    function stop() {

        echo "Releasing lock" . PHP_EOL;

        $this->lock->release();

    }

}


?>
```

The command itself:

```
class SomeCommand extends BaseCommandWrapper
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('processSomeCommand')
            ->setDescription('Process Some Command')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        if ($this->start($this->getName()) === false) {
            return 0;
        } 

        sleep(60);

        $this->stop();

    }
```

All commands are triggered by cron which is triggered every second in this case scenario.

Comment: Are you sure your production system is compatible with PHP Semaphore ? http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php

Comment: Yes, however when I changed it to FlockStore it works perfectly fine: $store = new FlockStore(sys_get_temp_dir()); $factory = new Factory($store);

Comment: Mm.. It does not make sense :D

Answer (score 0):

It might be linked to systemd RemoveIPC parameter :

> RemoveIPC=
>              Controls whether System V and POSIX IPC objects belonging to the
>              user shall be removed when the user fully logs out. Takes a
>              boolean argument. If enabled, the user may not consume IPC
>              resources after the last of the user's sessions terminated. This
>              covers System V semaphores, shared memory and message queues, as
>              well as POSIX shared memory and message queues. Note that IPC
>              objects of the root user and other system users are excluded from
>              the effect of this setting. Defaults to "yes".

If you are using systemd, then everytime the cron ends, the user logs out, and systemd removes the semaphore.

- First Cron acquires the lock
- Second Cron fails to acquire the lock, user logs out, semaphore is removed
- Thris Cron acquires the lock / First Cron does not have it anymore.

As discussed [in this thread](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2039), either you disable RemoveIPC on your server, or use a system user to avoid this. Or as you said in your comment : use another Store.

Most likely, you should have a warning :

> PHP Warning: sem_remove(): SysV semaphore 14071[redacted]0096 does not (any longer) exist in [redacted]/app/vendor/symfony/lock/Store/SemaphoreStore.php on line 95

Someone else encountered the issue : [in this thread](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29952#issuecomment-503345294), they should most likely add it to the documentation.